# Php send post vars in form

Tags: php, post

**if i put this :** NO WORKS

```
<?php
if($_POST['send']=="ok")
{
    print $_POST['opt']['nombre']
}
?>

<form action="" method="post" style="margin:0px;">
    <input type="text" name="opt['nombre']" value="Hello" />
    <input type="hidden" name="send" value="ok">
</form>
```

**If i Put this :** WORKS

```
<?php
if($_POST['send']=="ok")
{
    print $_POST['opt']['nombre']
}
?>

<form action="" method="post" style="margin:0px;">
    <input type="text" name="opt[nombre]" value="Hello" />
    <input type="hidden" name="send" value="ok">
</form>
```

Why Happend this , the only change it´s in input file this opt['nombre']  by opt[nombre]

I don´t understand why happend this, it´s possible fix this problem because i want put opt['nombre'], and i think it´s the right

When works the result i get it´s "Hello" but only change this symbol inside tags as [''] by []

DIFFERENCES WORKS AND NO WORKS WHEN SEND POST FORM :

SEND FORM AND DON´T GET HELLO

```
<input type="text" name="opt['nombre']" value="Hello" />
```

SEND FORM AND GET HELLO

```
<input type="text" name="opt[nombre]" value="Hello" />
```

**DIFFERENCE PUT INSIDE [] QUOTES AS 2 OR DON´T PUT, THANK´S**

Comment: Why would you not just use the way that works ???? THe way that works is the right way to do it. HTML is not PHP is not javascript etc etc

Comment: Don´t understand your question, my question it´s about why happend this i think must works the same in all cases and magic_quotes in php it´s turn off and also try with turn on and result it´s the same i want know why happend this and know the problem and which it´s the way right for writte but if you put me negative for this i think this places it´s a wrong site for send simple question when i don´t know something, and if you read the problem it´s with result in php when use ' inside [] read first the question because it´s simple question

Comment: You are writing HTML and NOT PHP

Comment: This line is HTML `<input type="text" name="opt[nombre]" value="Hello" />`

Comment: This line is PHP `print $_POST['opt']['nombre']`

Comment: They are not that same animal at all and have different rules and syntax

Comment: Continue to don´t understand nothing, if i put in the html code [''] don´t get result in php, when send form if use in html code in the name of input type [] with out '' i get result when use post in php, i think the question it´s clear, i test this wit magic_quotes disabled and enabled with the same result

Comment: Possibly this would also be useful information for you then regarding Magic Quotes - **Warning** ___This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0.___ And PHP7.3 is the current version of PHP. _What version of PHP are you using?_

Comment: I know it´s deprecated but i use also php 5.3 sorry but show as you kidding me because my question it´s very simple, in actual example i have input type text with name as this 1 ) opt['name'] and opt[name] without quotes inside, if launch form when use without quotes show me result, if use with quotes inside don´t show me result when submit form, my question ut´s about why happend this because in one case form give me result and in other writte html no give me result from php

Comment: When you dont get a result, it is because you are using the wrong HTML syntax. Correct syntax is `name="opt[nombre]"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var_dump($_POST)` and take a look at the keys. You'll see the difference. The single quotes in the HTML `name` attribute become part of the string key in the PHP array when you do it the first way. You'd have to access it with the single quotes as part of the string to get it.

```
print $_POST['opt']["'nombre'"];
```

Or better yet, just do it the second way, so your PHP code won't have to use a silly key like that. :-)

Comment: Thanks `Don't`  Its late and my patience is frazzled

Comment: Ok thank´s for explain me this point, i want know this, thank´s, incredible other people don´t understand this single question, thank´s

Comment: @RiggsFolly I understand, it happens